# How to Java Triangle pattern printing with height

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to do this if the height is 3

```
AA
BBAA
AABBAA
```

and If the height is 7, then the following pattern is printed

```
AA
BBAA
AABBAA
BBAABBAA
AABBAABBAA
BBAABBAABBAA
AABBAABBAABBAA
```

So far, I did this

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class P4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int height;
    String A = "AA";
    String B = "BB";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your height: ");
    height = sc.nextInt();


    for(int i = 0; i < height+1; i++) {

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.print("A"); 
        }

        System.out.println(); 
    }


}

}
```

and my output is

```
Enter your height: 
3

A
AA
AAA
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include a question in your question.

Comment: Why do you use `System.out.print("A"); ` and not `System.out.print(A);`? Also, you didn't print `B`.

Comment: i did but more AA will appear, as for B idk where to put it

Comment: Hint: you are asking how to print a **pattern** using two variables. But none of your code makes **any** attempt of even trying to print a pattern. That very much looks like you got some homework, and want **us** to fill the gaps left open in your input template.

Comment: No ur wrong, I used the variable earlier for testing purposes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code sample

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        int height;
        String A = "AA";
        String B = "BB";

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your height: ");
        height = sc.nextInt();


        for (int i=1; i<=height; i++){
            for (int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
                if ((j%2) == 1) {
                    System.out.print((i%2 == 1) ? A: B);
                } else {
                    System.out.print((i%2 == 1) ? B :A);
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is only printing 'A', like you coded, you want to print double AA, ie 'AA'.

And after every odd iteration, i.e 1,3,5,7..., you want to print 'BB' too. This then will be inside your second loop, 'if even'.

```
for i < height
  if i % 2 is 0
    print 'BB'
  else
    print 'AA'
  print newline
```

like so.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the inside loop also

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int height;
String A = "AA";
String B = "BB";
String res="";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your height: ");
height = sc.nextInt();

for(int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
    if(i%2==0){
        res=B+res;
    }else{
        res=A+res; 
    }
    System.out.println(res);
}
}
```

It will print what you want, at each iteration your are adding a AA or a BB at your res

Answer (score -1):

An alternative solution...

```
public static final String A = "AA";
public static final String B = "BB";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Input your height");
    final Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height = inputScanner.nextInt();

    String currentToken;
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        currentToken = i%2==1?B:A;
        for(int j = i; j >= 0; j--){
            System.out.print(currentToken);
            currentToken = changeToken(currentToken);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }

}

private static String changeToken(String currentToken){
    return currentToken.equals(A)?B:A;
}
```